# How to use comaprision in this case

Tags: php, mysql, string-comparison

if(isset($_POST["request"])){

```
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $p_name = $_POST['p_name'];
  $noc = $_POST['noc'];
  $year = $_POST['year'];


  $get_email = "select email from book where email = '$email' ";
  $run_email = mysqli_query($con,$get_email);
  $check = mysqli_num_rows($run_email);

  if($check==1){

    echo "<script>alert('You Have Already Booked') </script>";
    exit();
  }

    $get_name = "SELECT capacity from party where type_party='$p_name' ";
    $run_name = mysqli_query($con,$get_name);
    $checkk = $run_name > '$noc';

  if(checkk){

    echo "<script>alert('Out Of Bound') </script>";
    exit();
    }
```

How to Compare capacity from party table with that the value of $noc??
Please help me out. Thank You!

Comment: what is "noc"? please explain you condition.

Comment: $noc(number of children) is just a variabe. If number of children in party table exceeds the value in $noc it cant proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `$` in last condition.

```
<?php
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $p_name = $_POST['p_name'];
  $noc = $_POST['noc'];
  $year = $_POST['year'];


  $get_email = "select email from book where email = '$email' ";
  $run_email = mysqli_query($con,$get_email);
  $check = mysqli_num_rows($run_email);

  if($check==1){

    echo "<script>alert('You Have Already Booked') </script>";
    exit();
  }

    $get_name = "SELECT capacity from party where type_party='$p_name' ";
    $run_name = mysqli_query($con,$get_name);
    $checkname = mysqli_num_rows($run_name );
    //$checkk = $run_name > '$noc';

  if($checkname > $noc){

    echo "<script>alert('Out Of Bound') </script>";
    exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad but it is still not working even though the value is lesser it still says "Out Of bound"

Comment: $checkname  has to be greater than $noc if less it has to be out of bound
, this code if i use ">" adds all data and if used "<" says ou of bound to all data.

Answer (score 0):

Just change you code like below.

```
$get_name = "SELECT capacity from party where type_party='$p_name' ";
$run_name = mysqli_query($con,$get_name);
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($run_name);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_name );

// please use any one condition which meet your requirement.
$checkk = $run_name > $noc;
// or
$checkk = $rows['capacity'] > $noc; 
// if it's not working try below
$checkk = $rows[0]['capacity'] > $noc;


if($checkk){
    echo "<script>alert('Out Of Bound') </script>";
    exit();
}
```

I get the number of results found from the query using "mysqli_num_rows" and then compare with $noc for proper result. Or else use the second condition to compare $noc with "$run_name['capacity']".

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\rima\functions\U_book.php on line 29

shows this error

Comment: just change $run_name['capacity'] to $run_name->capacity. I have update my answer please check.

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$capacity in C:\xampp\htdocs\rima\functions\U_book.php on line 32

Comment: Hello, I update my answer please check it, I have added the "mysqli_fetch_assoc" for fetching the records of select query before used it.